# how can I find my system's gcc compile flags?

Tags: macos, gcc, flags

I use OSX. I need to find all of my system's gcc compile flags. But I don't know how. Does it have a command?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean configuration options passed to GCC's `configure` script at the time it was built, then `gcc -v` is the command.

Comment: Good thinking! I hadn't thought it could mean that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
gcc -help
```

**Output**

```
OVERVIEW: clang LLVM compiler

USAGE: clang [options] <inputs>

OPTIONS:
  -###                    Print (but do not run) the commands to run for this compilation
  --analyzer-output <value>
                          Static analyzer report output format (html|plist|plist-multi-file|plist-html|text).
  --analyze               Run the static analyzer
  -arcmt-migrate-emit-errors
                          Emit ARC errors even if the migrator can fix them
  -arcmt-migrate-report-output <value>
                          Output path for the plist report
  -B <dir>                Add <dir> to search path for binaries and object files used implicitly
  -CC                     Include comments from within macros in preprocessed output
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a list of the default `#define`'s, then try this:

```
$ gcc -E -dM - </dev/null
#define __DBL_MIN_EXP__ (-1021)
#define __FLT32X_MAX_EXP__ 1024
#define __UINT_LEAST16_MAX__ 0xffff
#define __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE 2
#define __FLT128_MAX_10_EXP__ 4932
....
```

F.ex. if you are looking at a piece of flagging that uses GNU GCC version and you need to know the exact values for your version, then you can filter the list

```
$ gcc -E -dM - </dev/null | fgrep GNU
#define __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__ 1
#define __GNUC__ 8
#define __GNUC_RH_RELEASE__ 2
#define __GNUC_STDC_INLINE__ 1
#define __GNUC_MINOR__ 3
```